# I can't access with the package name when I run my application

Tags: java, android

I recently download a sample and I want to add this to my project.
when I make a new project everything looks like the sample and there is no diffrences between them.
but when I run the application I got this error.

Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?

please help me to solve this problem.
I'm new with android :-(

Comment: Are you using Android Studio? If so, is it updated? Because old version (very old) had bug.

Comment: No, I use intelij ... I got this error too , unfortunatult, share(my project) has stop